# output in f# interactive windows seems to make no sense, and does not match tutorial video

Tags: visual-studio, f#, interactive, f#-interactive

I am right now following some f# tutorial videos where i have copied the following code

```
let prefix strONE strTWO =
    strONE + " , " + strTWO
prefix "append" "theseTwo"
```

Pretty simple stuff, taking two string and putting them together.
I am using the interactive window to read output, which after some trouble is now working

in the video i am watching the guy is able to the output of the two strings being appended together, which is what i also want, but the only thing I am getting is this:

```
C:\Users\Ask\source\repos\File1.fs(7,1): warning FS0020: The result of this expression has type 'string' and is implicitly ignored. Consider using 'ignore' to discard this value explicitly, e.g. 'expr |> ignore', or 'let' to bind the result to a name, e.g. 'let result = expr'.

namespace FSI_0002
  val prefix : strONE:string -> strTWO:string -> string
```

What is happening? why am i not able to get my actual output?

UPDATE:

as suggested i tried creating a f# script file and doing the same. the output was still

```
[Loading C:\Users\Ask\source\repos\Script1.fsx]
 namespace FSI_0003
 val prefix : strONE:string -> strTWO:string -> string
```

Comment: It looks like it's working to me now.  You aren't getting the warning anymore.  However, it appears as if you didn't run the last line where you actually call the `prefix` function.  Running the first two lines will get you the function declaration, as your output shows.  Running the last line should give you the output of calling the function, like this:  `val it : string = "append , theseTwo"`  Try highlighting just the last line and pressing ALT+ENTER.

Comment: ah cool :) when i do that though it gives me:
' Script1.fsx(6,1): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'prefix' is not defined. '

Comment: It's possible you inadvertently reset the interactive session in between evaluating the definition and the call; you'll have to evaluate the full file again to get your desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're in a regular source file editor (`.fs`) and not an interactive script file (`.fsx`).  Try going to `File -> New -> File -> Script -> F# Script File` and using the interactive F# script editor it opens at that point.

Comment: ahh, would that also explain why it starts comlaining that it needs me to declare a module?

Comment: @s3j80 Yes, that's likely why.